# How to access the files from USB Storage Device in Android Tablet Programmatically?

Tags: android

I am using android tablet. I have connected USB Storage Device ( Pendrive ) to android tablet. I don't know how to access the files are in USB Storge Device ( Pendrive ).

Comment: @Barak - that's probably not a good question to point to since it was mis-titled (fixed that) and getting irrelevant answers as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android detect usb storage for kitkat (4.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208297/android-detect-usb-storage-for-kitkat-4-4). There I posted solutions for both pre-6.0 and 6.0/above.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for the [android.hardware.usb package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html).